# Multiple LEFT JOIN conditions vs. WHERE

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

Example 1:

```
FROM
    table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON
        table1.id = table2.id
        AND
        table2.flag = TRUE
```

Example 2:

```
FROM
    table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON
        table1.id = table2.id
WHERE
    table2.flag = TRUE
```

Q1: Will both of these return the same number of rows? If not, why?

Q2: Which one is better?

Comment: @Dai The Both Queries are not equivalent, 
because the first query will select all the records from first table and joins the rows from second table if the fulfill the joining condition.
While the second query will skip all the records which do not fulfill the where clause.

Comment: @RaoFarhan Argh, I misread the queries as using `INNER JOIN` not `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - yes, you're rigth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not produce(might not) same result.
As soon as you use a column from your `LEFT JOIN`ed table in where clause it acts like the `LEFT` part will not be considered.

As per your 2nd question, `Which one is better`, This is not a matter of better or worse, it totally depends on what your need of result is.

Here is an example

`Create table1`

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `main_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`main_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `table1`(`main_id`,`first_name`,`flag`) values (1,'FIRST',1),(2,'SECOND',1),(5,'FIFTH',1);

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `main_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`main_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `table2`(`main_id`,`last_name`,`flag`) values (2,'THIRD',0),(4,'FORTH',1);
```

Your schema is now ready, Now try the following query:

Query 1

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  table1 t1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.`main_id` = t2.`main_id` 
    AND t2.`flag` = FALSE;
RESULT:


main_id  first_name    flag  main_id  last_name    flag  
-------  ----------  ------  -------  ---------  --------
      1  FIRST            1   (NULL)  (NULL)       (NULL)
      2  SECOND           1        2  THIRD             0
      5  FIFTH            1   (NULL)  (NULL)       (NULL)
```

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  table1 t1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.`main_id` = t2.`main_id` 
WHERE t2.`flag` = FALSE 


main_id  first_name    flag  main_id  last_name    flag  
-------  ----------  ------  -------  ---------  --------
      2  SECOND           1        2  THIRD             0
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the number of rows that Example 1 and Example 2 return isn't ensured to be equal. Even though there isn't a match that meets the requirement in the right table, Example 1 still contains all of the rows from the left table. Whereas in case of example 2 Only the rows where the condition is met are included.

In answer of your second question, depending on whether you want to include all rows from the left table (Example 1) or only rows where the condition is satisfied (Example 2), you can choose between Example 1 and Example 2. Make your selection depending on your unique needs.

Hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The Both Queries are not equivalent.
Because the first query will select all the records from first table and joins the rows from second table if they fulfill the joining condition. and will not skip any row from table1
While the second query will skip all the records which do not fulfill the **where clause**. In this second case the join will work like an inner join. [i.e if the rows fulfilling the joining condition exist in both tables then select else skip].

Answer (score 0):

When you outer join table2 (`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN table2`), then you still get a result row for a table1 row that has no match in table2. This means you'll get a result row consisting of the table1 row's values plus all table2 columns set to NULL. Now with `WHERE table2.flag = TRUE` you'd remove those outer joined rows, because in these rows `table2.flag` is NULL, not TRUE. In other words: your `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join.

> Q1: Will both of these return the same number of rows? If not, why?

As long as every table1 row has a match in table2, they will return the same rows. As soon as at least one table1 row has no match in table2, the first query will return rows that the second query does not.

> Q2: Which one is better?

The first query is definitely "better", because it is well-written. It shows an outer join that behaves as an outer join. The second query is an inner joined actually as explained above, so it should be written as an inner join in order to be equally "good":

```
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table2.flag = TRUE
```